# laravel eloquent get related tasks based on a auth user and project id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, belongs-to, relationships

Hi I'm confused as how I should write my eloquent query I want to retrieve the auth `user` `project` by its id and also fetch its related `tasks` these have a `hasMany` relationship, I also want to fetch the related client, to who the project belongs to, this is in the `projects` and the `tasks` table `client_id` ideally I want to visit this page at something like `app.dev/project/3/tasks` thats simple enough to route to:

```
Route::any("project/{resource}/tasks", [
        "as"   => "project/projectrelatedtasks",
        "uses" => "ProjectController@projectrelatedtasks"
    ]);
```

I'm not sure what the easiest way to write this query would be,  I can easy fetch want I need below in bulk like so in my repository:

```
public function getProjectTasks() {
//This fetches the auth users projects, the client to who it belongs and its related tasks
//not sure how to insert another find with $id 
    return \User::with(array('projects', 'projects.clients', 
    'projects.tasks'))->find(Auth::user()->id);
}
```

and this in my controller:

```
public function projectrelatedtasks() {
            $projects = $this->project->getProjectTasks();
            return $projects;
        }
```

but I want to limit it to a project by its id, not sure what the best and most efficient way to perform this query, can somebody help me figure this out please? thanks

### Edit

Repository:

```
public function getProjectTasks($id) {

    return \Projects::with(['clients', 'tasks'])
        ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
        ->find($project_id);
}
```

routes:

```
Route::any("project/{resource}/tasks", [
        "as"   => "project/projectrelatedtasks",
        "uses" => "ProjectController@projectrelatedtasks"
    ]);
```

controller:

```
public function projectrelatedtasks($id)
    {

    // get the Project tasks
        $project = $this->project->getProjectTasks($id);
        return $project;        
    }
```

error log:

```
[2014-09-10 20:56:50] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php:5687
Stack trace:
#0 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(5004): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(4992): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(4984): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(717): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(698): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(7706): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(8309): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(8256): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(10895): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(659): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 {main} [] []
```

Error log 2

```
[2014-09-10 21:01:58] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: project_id' in /media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/Acme/Repositories/DbProjectRepository.php:64
Stack trace:
#0 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/Acme/Repositories/DbProjectRepository.php(64): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/media/sf_Sites...', 64, Array)
#1 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/controllers/ProjectController.php(40): Acme\Repositories\DbProjectRepository->getProjectTasks('55')
#2 [internal function]: ProjectController->projectrelatedtasks('55')
#3 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(5784): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('projectrelatedt...', Array)
#5 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(5772): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(ProjectController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'projectrelatedt...')
#6 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(4971): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'ProjectControll...', 'projectrelatedt...')
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}('55')
#8 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(5330): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#9 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(4996): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(4984): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(717): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(698): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(7706): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#14 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(8309): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(8256): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(10895): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#17 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(659): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#19 {main} [] []
```

Comment: So you want to get a project by its `id` only if it belongs to a `user`?

Comment: yes, but I also want to retrieve its related client so I can output this onto the front end @Kousha

Comment: Okay, give me a sec. I'm writing the solution

Comment: Actually one question: why are you starting with the `User`? Why not directly start with the `Project`? There should be a pivot table or something that already links `User` to `Project`

Comment: @Kousha yes I have a user_id in the projects table, so i guess I could start at the Project, but how would I query two id''s, thats where im really confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the table inside the `with` using a closure:

```
// Assume $project_id is defined as the id of the project of interest
$user = User::with([
    'projects' => function($query) use ($project_id)
    {
        return $query->whereId($project_id);
    },
    'projects.clients',
    'projects.tasks'
])->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

But you should just start with the `Project` itself, since the table `projects` has a column `user_id`:

```
// Again, assuming $project_id is defined
Projects::with(['clients', 'tasks'])
        ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
        ->find($project_id);
```

Comment: thanks @kousha, I've tried this but I've got this error: `production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php:5687
Stack trace:` i've updated my question with code I've used

Comment: @g_9020, this is a routing issue, and not a controller issue. I'll check your routing right now. In the meantime, have a second look at your routing and make sure everything is set up properly.

Comment: sorry I've fixed the routing Ive got a different error now class Projects now found undefined variable

Comment: @g_9020, your Route doesn't include a wildcard (the `$id`). So the path you are providing `project/projectrelatedtasks/23` for example, is not routed at all. Have a look at this page http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Comment: @g_9020, yes because to the function `getProjectTasks()` you are passing the variable `$id` but in the query your are using `$project_id`! Change them to the same variable~!

Comment: @g_9020, good! Glad this solved your problem :). good luck with the rest of your coding

Comment: thanks, quick question whats wrong with this foreach it doesn't output any data :   `@foreach ($project->tasks as $project) {{ $project->project_name }} {{ $project->project_brief }} @if(!is_null($project->clients)) {{ $project->clients->client_name }} @endif @if(!is_null($project->tasks)) {{ $project->tasks->task_name }} @endif @endforeach`

Comment: if i remove the if statements i get this error Next exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object how can i construct this foreach

Comment: Um, you are looping through the `tasks` not the `project` (that's what your `foreach` code has: `$project->tasks as ...`. Based on what you wanted, you only get ONE project (because you are providing an `$id`).

Comment: I tried that too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775396/laravel-blade-foreach-fetching-related-tasks-to-projects-trying-to-get-property

Comment: @g_9020, let's go to the other post.