# laravel blade foreach fetching related tasks to projects 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hi I am trying to output all the related tasks to a Project but I am getting 'Trying to get property of non-object' in my error log so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, does anyone have any ideas?

This is my view which has the foreach

```
{{ $project->project_name }}
    {{ $project->project_brief }}
    {{ $project->clients->client_name }}

   @foreach ($project->tasks as $project)
    {{ $project->tasks->task_name }}
    @endforeach
```

This is my repository which performs the query

```
public function getProjectTasks($project_id) {

    return \Project::with(['clients', 'tasks'])
        ->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)
        ->find($project_id);
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function projectrelatedtasks($project_id)
    {

    // get the Project tasks
        $project = $this->project->getProjectTasks($project_id);
    return View::make('projects.projectrelatedtasks')
            ->with('project', $project);        
        }
```

but I get this error:

```
Next exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object (View: /media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/views/projects/projectrelatedtasks.blade.php)' in /media/sf_Sites/tempus/app/storage/views/6e987b895513269a7fde1cd2f82fc6a1:12
Stack trace:
#0 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(9742): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException))
#1 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(56): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/media/sf_Sites...', Array)
#2 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(9619): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/media/sf_Sites...', Array)
#3 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(9606): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#4 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(9597): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#5 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(10295): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(9826): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#7 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(5190): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#8 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(4998): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#9 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(4984): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(717): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(698): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(7706): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#13 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(8309): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#14 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(8256): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#15 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(10895): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#16 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/bootstrap/compiled.php(659): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /media/sf_Sites/tempus/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#18 {main} [] []
```

Does anyone know how I can construct this foreach to fetch all the related tasks to a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is wrong. It should be

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
    {{ $task->task_name }}
@endforeach
```

Your are looping through all the `tasks` so the second argument in the `foreach` is the `task` itself.

Comment: @g_9020, Good! The Symphony errors are usually pretty good at telling you what the problem is. Learn to read and love them!

Comment: @g_9020, and if you don't mind, can you select this as an answer if it helped you?